# How to read a long http response body

Tags: android, json

I use 
HttpURLConnection  [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events-that-a-user-has-received) in Android to read the event of my github account.The http library I use is Volley.

The URL I request is https://api.github.com/users/Leaking/received_events/public

The respones is a json array.And when the length of this json array is long enough(maybe bigger than 10),I lose to read all the json array and just read part of the json array string.like below

I wonder if the response body is too long to read.

```
[
{
    "id": "2958450223",
    "type": "WatchEvent",
    "actor": {
        "id": 1114542,
        "login": "nvbn",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/nvbn",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1114542?"
    },
    "repo": {
        "id": 6817270,
        "name": "fsantanna/ceu",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/fsantanna/ceu"
    },
    "payload": {
        "action": "started"
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2015-07-08T21:26:51Z"
},
{
    "id": "2956734206",
    "type": "WatchEvent",
    "actor": {
        "id": 1169522,
        "login": "Trinea",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Trinea",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1169522?"
    },
    "repo": {
        "id": 23112526,
        "name": "android10/Android-CleanArchitecture",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture"
    },
    "payload": {
        "action": "started"
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2015-07-08T13:12:49Z"
},
{
    "id": "2956726542",
    "type": "WatchEvent",
    "actor": {
        "id": 1169522,
        "login": "Trinea",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Trinea",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1169522?"
    },
    "repo": {
        "id": 38324286,
        "name": "cooltechworks/BitmapMerger",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/cooltechworks/BitmapMerger"
    },
    "payload": {
        "action": "started"
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2015-07-08T13:10:20Z"
},
{
    "id": "2956721687",
    "type": "WatchEvent",
    "actor": {
        "id": 1169522,
        "login": "Trinea",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Trinea",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1169522?"
    },
    "repo": {
        "id": 37834277,
        "name": "openstf/stf",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/openstf/stf"
    },
    "payload": {
        "action": "started"
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2015-07-08T13:08:46Z",
    "org": {
        "id": 12196621,
        "login": "openstf",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/openstf",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/12196621?"
    }
},
{
    "id": "2956719107",
    "type": "WatchEvent",
    "actor": {
        "id": 1169522,
        "login": "Trinea",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Trinea",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1169522?"
    },
    "repo": {
        "id": 14712620,
        "name": "CyberAgent/adbkit",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/CyberAgent/adbkit"
    },
    "payload": {
        "action": "started"
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2015-07-08T13:07:58Z",
    "org": {
        "id": 865695,
        "login": "CyberAgent",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/CyberAgent",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/865695?"
    }
},
{
    "id": "2956716059",
    "type": "WatchEvent",
    "actor": {
        "id": 1169522,
        "login": "Trinea",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Trinea",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1169522?"
    },
    "repo": {
        "id": 4397781,
        "name": "wsieroci/audiorecognizer",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/wsieroci/audiorecognizer"
    },
    "payload": {
        "action": "started"
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2015-07-08T13:06:55Z"
},
{
    "id": "2956704073",
    "type": "WatchEvent",
    "actor": {
        "id": 1169522,
        "login": "Trinea",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Trinea",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1169522?"
    },
    "repo": {
        "id": 3586085,
        "name": "SimonVT/android-numberpicker",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/SimonVT/android-numberpicker"
    },
    "payload": {
        "action": "started"
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2015-07-08T13:02:44Z"
},
{
    "id": "2956697058",
    "type": "WatchEvent",
    "actor": {
        "id": 1169522,
        "login": "Trinea",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Trinea",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1169522?"
    },
    "repo": {
        "id": 36551310,
        "name": "tittojose/TimeRangePicker",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/tittojose/TimeRangePicker"
    },
    "payload": {
        "action": "started"
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2015-07-08T13:00:20Z"
},
{
    "id": "2956696712",
    "type": "WatchEvent",
    "actor": {
        "id": 1169522,
        "login": "Trinea",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/us!!!!!I just read half of it.
```

Comment: You can use `Postman` or http://requestmaker.com.

Comment: how you getting this response(is from logcat)?

Comment: @KrishnaV    Yeah,I get the response and print it

Comment: it gets all the response but logcat not showing large text(it shows fixed characters length). for testing store in file and then see.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I fix it.As you say, logcat not showing large text.

Answer (score 0):

I use to read response from server by using Postman app. In google chrome you can find it here [Chrome Postman - REST Client shortcut](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwijl_eK043LAhWk2aYKHa83A1gQFggsMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fpostman-rest-client-short%2Fmkhojklkhkdaghjjfdnphfphiaiohkef%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNFwYFZdlRp9JhjEYWIlLxW8odw-6A&sig2=naCY92kShGEN5RNoIz9l9Q)

The tools is really useful to help you be more efficient while working with APIs.

The fun thing it can provide formatted API responses for JSON and XML.

Hope it help.